# Angular Firebase Authentication issue - custom userModel

Tags: typescript, firebase, authentication, angular2-services

I'm still quite new to Angular, and the project that I'm currently working on is using Firebase for database, hosting, and authorization purposes.
I have been following some tutorials from the web and I am stuck.
The Sign-up and Sign-In functions are not working as intended because my userModel must be different than in the found [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/full-angular-firebase-authentication-system/#tc_784_07).
My model needs to have more fields and here is where the problem lies.

Below are the snippets of my code:

**user.model.ts**

```
  export interface UserModel {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  photoURL: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
}
```

**auth-service.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModel } from 'src/app/models/user.model'
import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data
  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore, // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) {
    /* Saving user data in localstorage when
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', 'null');
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      }
    });
  }
  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }
  // Sign up with email/password
  SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign
        up and returns promise */
        this.SendVerificationMail();
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }
  // Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.afAuth.currentUser
      .then((u: any) => u.sendEmailVerification())
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
      });
  }
  // Reset Forggot password
  ForgotPassword(passwordResetEmail: string) {
    return this.afAuth
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
      .then(() => {
        window.alert('Password reset email sent, check your inbox.');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error);
      });
  }
  // Returns true when user is looged in and email is verified
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
    return user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false;
  }
  // Sign in with Google
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then((res: any) => {
      if (res) {
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      }
    });
  }
  // Auth logic to run auth providers
  AuthLogin(provider: any) {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error);
      });
  }
  /* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password,
  sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth
  provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
  SetUserData(user: UserModel) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserModel> = this.afs.doc(
      `users/${user.uid}`
    );
    const userData: UserModel = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    };

    return userRef.set(Object.assign({},userData) , {
      merge: true,
    });
  }
  // Sign out
  SignOut() {
    return this.afAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
    });
  }
}
```

I am getting such an error in SetUpUserMethod :  *TS2345: Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserModel'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.*

If I revert the service code to the original version as in the tutorial I get issues from Firebase instead:
*Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field firstName in document users/.......*

All in all, new credentials are added in the Auth section in the Firebase but not added in the Firestore. So I cannot use them to Sign-in as I am getting a similar error from Firebase: *Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field firstName in document users/x*

**sign-up.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService} from "../../services/auth-service.service";
import {AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    email: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl(''),
  });
  submitted = false;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(40)]],
      },
    );
  }

  get f(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.authService.SignUp(this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value, null, 2));
  }

  onReset(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.form.reset();
  }   
}
```

Is anyone willing to point in the right direction?
Later I plan to add an additional collection(to mark the progress - the language studying app) and connect it to each user using UID. That is why I need to have the details of the User in the Firestore as well.